# KotlinMultiplatform Cannot access 'kotlin.Cloneable'

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

How can I use the "Mac" encryption class in the shared Kotlin Multiplatform module? When I try this I see the error "Cannot access 'kotlin.Cloneable' which is a supertype of 'javax.crypto.Mac'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s0Is.png)

If you know another way to encrypt the string with the "HmacSHA512" algorithm using the key I would be very happy to see your way!

Comment: You can't use Java based libraries in KMM. Look for a library that supports KMM, or [create a wrapper](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-connect-to-apis.html) using expect/actual, and then use java based code in androidMain (or javaMain), and find an appropriate solution to be used in iOS part